# How to filter column based on maximum of another column for group of data in SSAS Query?

Tags: filter, dax

I am getting data from data warehouse (SSAS Query) and I am trying to filter data directly in query.

Let say that this is simple query:

```
  EVALUATE
  SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
  'Product'[Product],
  'Week'[WEEK],
  'SALES', [Sales Qty])
```

I got something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQYum.png)

What I need to do is filter the data based on MAX of Sales for SKU. So in SKU:

- '111' the max is in week 3 (220), so there should stay only weeks 3 to 6,
- '222' the max is in week 1 (100), so there should stay only weeks 1 to 6,
- '333' the max is actualy in two places (120), but there is need to take the lower one, so should stay weeks 4 to 6.

I tried to filter this in that way:

```
   EVALUATE
   FILTER(
      SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      'Product'[Product],
      'Week'[WEEK],
      'Sales', [Sales Qty]),
   'Week'[WEEK] >= CALCULATE(MAX('Week'[WEEK]), [Sales]=MAX([Sales])))
```

but can't get the [Sales] from this table -> ERROR "Cannot identify the table that contains [Sales] column"

Could you please help me with that? I am trying make that for few days and figured that it will be too hard for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
DEFINE
  TABLE p1 = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Product'[Product], 'Product'[WEEK], "Sales", [Sales Qty])
  VAR p2 = SUMMARIZE('p1', [Product], "firstMaxWeek", CALCULATE(MIN('p1'[Week]), FILTER('p1', 'p1'[Sales] = MAX('p1'[Sales]) )))
  VAR result = FILTER( NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(p1, p2), [WEEK] >= [firstMaxWeek] )
EVALUATE
  SUMMARIZE(result, [Product], [WEEK], [Sales]) ORDER BY [Product], [WEEK]
```

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome, please help mark it as the accepted answer.